# is_prime? in Ruby. Need a second opinion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, primes

I've been studying ruby and have been doing some ruby exercises to see how much i know (which isn't a whole lot).  Here's a problem I've come across:

Q:  Write a method, is_prime?, that takes a number num and returns true if it is prime and false otherwise.

You may wish to use the modulo operation: 5 % 2 returns the remainder when dividing 5 by 2: 1. If num is divisible by i, then num % i == 0. (You would not be expected to already know about modulo for the challenge)

The question also came with an answer, which is.

A:

```
# Works for values greater than 1

def is_prime?(num)
  i = 2
  while i < num
    is_divisible = ((num % i) == 0)

    if is_divisible
      # divisor found; stop and return false!
      return false
    end

    i += 1
  end

  # no divisors found
  true
end
```

This is what I came up with:

mA:

```
def is_prime?(num)
  if num % 2 == 0
    puts "false"
  else 
    puts "true"
  end
end
```

Since what I have is completely different from the answer, I could use someone backing me up to see if I'm on the right track.  Thank you.

Comment: A wee problem with your solution: is_prime?(2) => "false".  Start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

Comment: side note, in addition to the problems so far addressed in the answers, but your function should return true or false, not print it as a string

Answer (score 2):

Start writing automated tests. Specifically...

```
assert{ 5.is_prime }
deny{ 6.is_prime }
assert{ 7.is_prime }
deny{ 8.is_prime }
deny{ 9.is_prime }
```

If your `is_prime` used `return true` instead of `print "true"`, my last assertion would break it. (I'm using the Wrong library here, but you can use whatever `assert_true()` assertions came with your `test/unit` library.)

Keep adding assertions, and fixing your code when they break, until your code looks like that code. Then look up a standard implementation of "Sieve of Eratosthenes", to learn why that code is inefficient!

Comment: If running stand alone Ruby, try http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Unit_testing

Answer (score 2):

Your solution only checks whether the number is even or not, and as Cary Swoveland pointed out will incorrectly identify 2 as not prime. You'll also incorrectly identify numbers such as 9 or 15 as prime.

There are a couple of things you can do that can speed up the provided solution quite a bit:

1. After checking that the `num` isn't divisible by 2, you only need
   to inspect odd numbers past that point. Increment your candidate
   divisor by 2 rather than 1.
2. At the upper limit of the `while` loop, the largest candidate divisor you
   need to check is `Math.sqrt(num)`. Any factor of `num` that's larger
   than the square root has a co-factor which is smaller than the
   square root, so there's no point in looking at the larger
   candidates.

Comment: Proof of #2: `x = Math.sqrt(num).to_i`. If `n > x` is a factor of `num`, so is `num/n` and `num/n = x*num/x*n < x*num/x*x = x`.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution only works for determining if a number is divisible by 2.

For example, an input value of 9 would cause your function to return true, even though 9 is not prime.  It needs to iterate over all possible factors, not just 2, as it does in the sample solution.

Answer (score 0):

To do that by trial division which seems to be what you're trying to do, the simplest method would be to start at i=2 and do i % num == 0. then continuously increment i by 1 while i is less than num.

Also, to make this work for negative numbers, do a check to see if num <= 1. If it is, return false.

Optimization 1: (easy)
Don't go all the way up to the number. Only go up to the square root of the number.
To easily accomplish this, make your loop condition (i*i <= num)

Optimization 2: (challenging)
Start at 3 and then increment by 2 because any number that's divisible by 2 can't be a prime. Except for 2 of course.

To make this work, you need to add two more checks (read: if statements) at the beginning of your code. The first one checks if (num == 2). If it does, return true. The second checks if (num % 2 == 0). If it does, return false;

Optimization 3: (difficult)
You only need to check primes. If you generate and store a list of primes, you can use those primes to quickly find primes far greater than then the highest prime in your list. Once you understand optimization 2, you'll be able to write this pretty easily.

Once you master trial division you may want to check out the Sieve of Eratosthenes. It's cool beans and not too difficult to understand.